# Securing redirects based on return_to param in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, redirect

I've some actions redirecting back or to another location within my site that I pass with a parameter from the original page.

In my `application_controller.rb` I have this method, that I use in other controllers to get and process the param `return_to`

```
def redirect_to_return_to_or_default(default)
  if params[:return_to].present?
    redirect_to params[:return_to]
    return
  end

  redirect_to default
```

end

Reading the [Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection) I see this can be used in phishing attacks, so I'd like to secure it, probably by filtering `return_to` to redirect only to URLs within my domain.

Am I missing something? Any ideas on how to perform this in a simple and elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

I've added the following as a private method in my ApplicationController

```
  def redirect_to_param(token)
    unless token.blank?
      parsed_token = URI.parse(token)
      res = ""
      res << parsed_token.path
      unless parsed_token.query.blank?
        res << "?"
        res << parsed_token.query
      end
      return res
    end
  end
```

And then wherever I want to redirect to a user provided parameter, I say something like

```
redirect_to redirect_to_param(params[:redirect])
```

Would love feedback on how others are doing this as well.